# Эти странные теги SVG

Tags: svg

Странные какие-то эти теги в SVG. То они парные, то одиночные.
Не пойму, когда, какие применять.

Например, - встречаются две формы записи команды `<rect>` с разной формой записи закрывающего тега:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400"  viewBox="0 0 400 400" >

<rect x="10" y="10" width="200" height="100" fill="greenyellow" />
<rect x="220" y="10" width="200" height="100" fill="skyblue" </rect>

</svg>
```

Так как же правильно закрывать тег, если обе формы записи работают без сообщения об ошибке?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Разница в выполнении кода файла в браузере при расширениях (*.svg) и (*.html)

Эти две формы записи будут работать без сообщения об ошибке, но только, если код SVG встроен инлайн в HTML.
Если код SVG сохранён в standalone `*.svg` файл и  запустить его на выполнение, то будет выдано сообщение об ошибке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае, правильное закрывание тега `<rect` будет - `/>`

**Так зачем же применяются две формы записи закрывания тега?**

В синтаксисе SVG довольно строгая система   написания тегов. По порядку применения, теги можно разбить на три группы:

1. Тэги “хамелеон” – в зависимости от контекста могут быть одиночными или парными.
2. Одиночные тэги
3. Парные тэги
4. Тэги “хамелеон” – в зависимости от контекста могут быть одиночными или парными.
   --

Одиночный тэг – `<line ….. />` в примере ниже работает нормально.

`<line x1="5px" y1="100px" x2="200px" y2="50px" stroke="green"/>`

Допустим понадобилось добавить анимацию линии. Для этого внутрь одиночного тэга – `<line ….. />` добавляем одиночный тэг анимации – `<animate attributeName=”x2″ ….. />`

```
<line x1="5px" y1="100px" x2="200px" y2="50px" stroke="crimson"> 
            <animate attributeName="x2" dur="4s" begin="1s"
              values="5;50;100;150;200; 800" repeatCount="indefinite" />
/>
```

Получаем сообщение об ошибке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрите внимательно на код выше. Одиночный тег анимации вложен в одиночный тег линии. Парсер XML не понимает этого и подсказывает, что нужно изменить внешний одиночный тэг линии на парный `</line>`.

*Пример правильного закрытия тега `</line>`*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400"  viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
<line x1="5px" y1="100px" x2="200px" y2="50px" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="2"> 
            <animate
            attributeName="x2"
            dur="4s"
            begin="0.1s"
            values="5;100;200;400;800;400;200;100;5"
            repeatCount="indefinite" />                        
            
</line>
</svg>
```

**Вывод – одиночные теги базовых фигур SVG заменяются на парные теги, если внутри вложены одиночные теги анимации:**

`<animate … />`, `<animateTransform … />`, `<animateMotion … />`, `<animateColor … />`, `<set … />`

Это справедливо для всех основных фигур SVG:
`<line … />`, `<polyline … />`, `<polygon … />`, `<circle … />`, `<ellipse … />`, `<rect … />`,`<path … />` и `<use />`;

2. Одиночные тэги.
   --
   В этом разделе находятся тэги, которые всегда применяются, только как одиночные. Это тэги реализующие анимацию:
   `<animate … />`
   `<animateTransform … />`
   `<animateMotion … />`
   `<animateColor … />`
   `<set … />`

Анимационные теги всегда используются вместе с тегами объекта анимации. Они могут находится либо внутри тегов объекта анимации, либо использовать ссылку, `xlink:href=”#my-circle”` на внешний объект, см.  листинг ниже.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400"  viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
<circle id="my-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
  <animate 
    xlink:href="#my-circle"
    attributeName="cx"
    values="50;150;50"
    dur="2s"
    begin="0.5s"
    fill="freeze"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
 />

</svg>
```

В этом примере анимационный тег находится снаружи объекта анимации, поэтому тег объекта анимации `<line ... />` закрыт, как одиночный тег.

3. Парные теги
   --

В этом разделе находятся теги, которые всегда применяются, только как парные. В первую очередь это теги контейнерныx элементов, которые по определению могут содержать внутри себя другие графические элементы и другие контейнерные элементы в качестве потомков.

`<a> … </a>`
`<defs> … </defs>`
`<glyph> … </glyph>`
`<g> … </g>`
`<marker> … </marker>`
`<mask> … </mask>`
`<missing-glyph> … </missing-glyph>`
`<pattern> … </pattern>`
`<svg> … </svg>`
`<switch> … </switch>`
`<symbol> … </symbol>`

В спецификации SVG тегов много, перечислять все парные теги нет смысла.
Полный перечень [здесь](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermContainerElement).