# Как добавить на растровой карте анимированный маршрут до офиса

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Часто заказчики просят в разделе сайта "Контакты" добавить фрагмент карты с маршрутом до их офиса.

Вот например фрагмент карты Санкт-Петербурга. Допустим офис  находится во внутриквартальной территории между улицами Восстания и Лиговским проспектом. Картинка ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С прокладыванием статического маршрута замечательно справляется Yandex карты

Но необходимо, как-то анимировать этот статичный маршрут в виде рисования линии от метро до офиса.  Причём при изменении масштаба карты анимационная линия не должна смещаться в стороны относительно улиц карты, по которым проложен маршрут.

Другими словами, всё должно быть адаптивным, всё должно изменяться в размерах пропорционально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустимо применение любой техники для реализации анимации и адаптивности приложения: `svg`,`css`,`javascript` или все техники вместе.

*Это учебный вопрос-пример, но он дополнительно имеет и практическое применение. Допускается любое количество ответов, все будут отмечены.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74022/discussion-on-question-by-alexandr-tt------).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Первый шаг:**

- Начнём с того, что нам нужно найти место на карте (в данном случае
  будем использовать Яндекс.Карты). После этого нужно создать `path` с
  помощью векторного редактора [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/ru/download/) и сохранить в формате
  `.svg`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Второй шаг:**

- Достаём `path` из файла и включаем его в наш `HTML`-документ:
  **P.S.** Также мы добавим `background` у `viewport`'a c помощью тега `<image/>`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 900 1100">
 <image width="450" height="480" xlink:href="https://image.ibb.co/bD8na7/path_map.jpg" />
<path style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
      d="m 332.31772,426.61112 -2.13481,36.29166 -286.063642,-71.16011 9.250815,-36.29166 10.674016,-53.37008 17.078427,-67.6021 3.558005,-51.94688 4.269607,-49.81208 4.981208,-88.238538 7.116014,-17.078427 241.94437,9.250815 -2.1348,33.445252 V 177.55074 l -1.4232,69.02531 37.00325,2.1348 5.69281,-7.11601 h 4.26961 l 1.4232,-6.40441"/>
</svg>
```

- Теперь нам нужно изменить стили `path`, как показано на картинке(у автора данного вопроса):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 900 1100">
  <image width="450" height="480" xlink:href="https://image.ibb.co/bD8na7/path_map.jpg" />
  <path style="fill:none; opacity: 0.7; stroke: #A066FF;stroke-width:4px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
          d="m 332.31772,426.61112 -2.13481,36.29166 -286.063642,-71.16011 9.250815,-36.29166 10.674016,-53.37008 17.078427,-67.6021 3.558005,-51.94688 4.269607,-49.81208 4.981208,-88.238538 7.116014,-17.078427 241.94437,9.250815 -2.1348,33.445252 V 177.55074 l -1.4232,69.02531 37.00325,2.1348 5.69281,-7.11601 h 4.26961 l 1.4232,-6.40441"/>
</svg>
```

**Третий шаг (последний)**:

- Последняя задача - это создать анимацию `path`. Для этого мы
  изначально узнаем его длину, после добавим `stroke-dashoffset` &
  `stroke-dasharray` и заключим тег `<animate/>` внутрь самого `path`.

1. Чтобы узнать длину `path`, нам нужно написать функцию на JS:
 
    **P.S.** Допишем полученное число в `stroke-dashoffset` &    `stroke-dasharray`

```js
function LengthofPath() {
  var path = document.querySelector('#mainPath');
  var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength());
  alert("Length - " + len);
};
```

```html
<!--Повесим onclick на кнопку-->
<button onclick="LengthofPath()">Total Length</button>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 900 1100">
  <image width="450" height="480" xlink:href="https://image.ibb.co/bD8na7/path_map.jpg" />
  <path id="mainPath" stroke-dashoffset="1211" stroke-dasharray="1211" style="fill:none; opacity: 0.7; stroke: #A066FF;stroke-width:4px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
              d="m 332.31772,426.61112 -2.13481,36.29166 -286.063642,-71.16011 9.250815,-36.29166 10.674016,-53.37008 17.078427,-67.6021 3.558005,-51.94688 4.269607,-49.81208 4.981208,-88.238538 7.116014,-17.078427 241.94437,9.250815 -2.1348,33.445252 V 177.55074 l -1.4232,69.02531 37.00325,2.1348 5.69281,-7.11601 h 4.26961 l 1.4232,-6.40441"/>
</svg>
```

2. Осталось добавить анимацию в `path`:
**P.S.** [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/792782/280567) подробно изложено про парные и одиночные теги

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 900 1100">
  <image width="450" height="480" xlink:href="https://image.ibb.co/bD8na7/path_map.jpg" />
  <path stroke-dashoffset="1211" stroke-dasharray="1211" style="fill:none; opacity: 0.7; stroke: #A066FF;stroke-width:4px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
              d="m 332.31772,426.61112 -2.13481,36.29166 -286.063642,-71.16011 9.250815,-36.29166 10.674016,-53.37008 17.078427,-67.6021 3.558005,-51.94688 4.269607,-49.81208 4.981208,-88.238538 7.116014,-17.078427 241.94437,9.250815 -2.1348,33.445252 V 177.55074 l -1.4232,69.02531 37.00325,2.1348 5.69281,-7.11601 h 4.26961 l 1.4232,-6.40441">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" values="1211;0" dur="10s" fill="freeze" />
    <!--В value используем так называемый from to, длину path от 1211 до 0-->
  </path>
</svg>
```

Все фрагменты кода отображаются адаптивно, как и просил автор вопроса.

Comment: Здорово, только я почему-то думала, что ты без js сделаешь

Comment: @kizoso, JS был нужен для измерения `path`, не более, а в конечном варианте без него:)